# I cannot install ROS hydro in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu, ros

Does anyone Know how to install Fully desktop ROS hydro in ubuntu 13.10? Maybe with the source code but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version  of ROS indigo was released few weeks ago. This is the list of steps needed  to install ROS indigo in ubuntu 13.10:

1. Enable "restricted," "universe," and "multiverse" repsitories. You can do this in System > Administration > Software Sources. Check (restricted) (universe) and (multiverse) boxes
2. Setup your computer to accept software from packages.ros.org.
3. Set up your Keys
4. Finally, install

Detailed explanation in:

> http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu